# How are people without mac products testing their websites for compatibility issues on safari

Tags: html, safari

A friend was testing my website for me as he has a mac and safari.  The page has a form that takes user input and uses googles recaptcha.  When he proves to recaptcha he is not a bot and then submits the form the captcha response always returns false when tested on the calling script.

To add to the complication of the situation, I used my gfs ipad to try the recaptcha email form (different form but same site than my friend tested) and it worked and the email went through.  HOWEVER when I loaded the other page (the one my friend had tested ) safari on my gfs ipad crashes.  The page that crashes loads 10415 polygons on google maps api and I suspect this has something to do with crashing safari on the ipad (although I have no way to test this).

How are people without mac products testing their websites for compatibility issues on safari. Are there known compatibility issues that I should investigate based on the information I have provided.  The site submits records on both pages fine in iexplore, chrome, firefox and operah

Chris

Answer (score 1):

You can also use EQUAFY as cross-browser testing tool to aid you in testing your web app on Safari browser

Answer (score 0):

You can use cloud based online testing platform ,they will provide you the facility to test on multiple browser with different versions available. For example you can use 
[browser stack](https://www.browserstack.com/)

Answer (score 0):

While most businesses who make web based apps will have a range of physical devices to use, there are some options for testing emulated devices.

[Browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com) is one option.

Additionally, a service like this is often used to run [automated end to end testing](https://www.browserstack.com/automate). This will ensure breaks do not happen in your app as long as all code you develop is fully tested.